# Looking for Java PDF generator with configurable at runtime document schemas

Tags: java, pdf

I'm searching for a framework which allows to generate pdf files from java beans or data sources using xml as configuration file. (In fact data interface will be the same but document's structure or style may change on runtime). I've considered using iText for this purpose but it requires to write java code for each document type. Maybe there's some wrapper for this lib available?

Comment: "Document type?"  Output type?  Code for each report?  What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to code i Java to get PDF ro the problem is there is too many possible document types ? **Standardize** on document type and then **consider using either iText or XSL** (Apache FOP?). As for wrapper for Java objects, you can **use reflection** to make yourself generic one.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know for now how many doc types will I have so I want to leave a possibility to add document types without recompiling my code.

Comment: Than use reflection to genrate PDF ror any Java object. 

As for other types of input, you can represent them as Java objects too - of course you'll need to create class for each of them but you'll work with classes as DatabaseTable or CSV File etc.